# WiX Custom Action - Pass file list

Tags: installation, wix, wix3.6

I am preparing installation packages for a plugin which replace some files of other application. I need make a backup of that files, so I prepared *CustomAction* which will do that.

How can I pass as argument to my custom action locations of all files which will be copied during installation? Do I need to make that list manually?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a custom action, why not use the [WiX CopyFile](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_copyfile.htm) element to back up those files.

Comment: The main problem is that during Uninstall files created by CopyFile will be also removed.

Comment: You are copying files that already exist on the machine correct? In that case I doubt they will be removed on uninstall.

Comment: Yes, they already exist. I had just put CopyFile inside File tag so it had caused such behavior. When I put CopyFile inside Component it made backup of existing file, but new file is the same as old file. Probably I need to do more research. How to move backup file to original state on uninstall ?

Comment: Hmm...it sounds like a sequencing issue. The file is getting installed before it gets copied. I would definitely keep it in the component (and not under the file element) and then see if you can change the sequencing of the InstallExecuteSequence. That's my guess. However if you need to copy the files back to the original state on uninstall (and if the copyfile task doesn't automatically do that), then you may have to create a custom action because you couldn't just use other copyfile elements.

Comment: Hmm, so we are back to the beginning. How to pass file structure to custom action...

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters to custom actions by setting properties in your installer. Then access those properties in your custom action like so (C# example):

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult DoWork(Session session)
{
    session.Log("Begin DoWork");
    string propertyValue = session["PROPERTYNAME"];
    //...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know about that. My question was whether it is necessary to create manually list of files which should be passed as property to custom action, or can I use files list from already defined components?