# Wix Toolset write installation path to file

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3, wix3.7, wix3.6

I created a .msi installer that copies some files in a chosen directory.
I have one .properties file with hard coded path strings that are used in the application. How can I write the installation path in the .properties file that is provided by the installation so that the application can get the written installation path from the .properties file at runtime.

It is important that the installation path is written to a file that will be installed by the installer. A registry setting with the installation directory will not be suitable.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom action that runs (after the files were moved to their final location) that edits\rewrites the properties file to include the new paths.

Creating a custom action: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixdev/extensions/authoring_custom_actions.html

(You can pass the filename as parameter to the custom action: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10953940/1632576)